# How can I convert a double to a Hex string?

Tags: vba

I'm working on editing a project in visual basic, and don't have a whole lot of experience with vb.

I have a text box where a user can enter a number.  The number should be stored as a double.  Then, I need to convert the number to it's equivalent 16-byte hexadecimal representation.  Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Hex function (works in VBA): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/963zt96e(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Mikegrann however, the decimal part will be rounded.

Comment: Yeah, I need a 16 byte hex value, no matter what the number is.  So, if I enter 10, it should return 4024000000000000, not A.

Comment: Then: http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/976138-post3.html (VBA doubles are 8 bytes, so you'll have to pad it out to 16 manually).

Comment: This needs more detail. What floating point encoding do you need the resulting 16 byte hex value to be in?   [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format)? If so, this isn't an issue of simply padding - the number of exponent bits are different as well as the exponent bias.

Comment: I'm sorry, I believe the hex value would be 8 bytes (64 bits).  It is in IEEE 754 format.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this kind of problem. My idea was to take the time from the function Now() and to split it by the comma. Then to convert it to Hex. After some time of researching, I came up with the idea that the input should be rounded. to 8, otherwise we may get an overflow error. This is my code:

```
Public Function codify_time() As String

    If [set_in_production] Then On Error GoTo codify_Error

    Dim dbl_01                  As Variant
    Dim dbl_02                  As Variant
    Dim dbl_now                 As Double

    dbl_now = Round(Now(), 8)

    dbl_01 = Split(CStr(dbl_now), ",")(0)
    dbl_02 = Split(CStr(dbl_now), ",")(1)

    codify_time = Hex(dbl_01) & "_" & Hex(dbl_02)

   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Function

codify_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure codify of Function TDD_Export"

End Function
```